# Romantic words to describe flavors

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I am working in a brewery and throughout our day we go through beer tasting panels. During these panels we attempt to describe the exact flavors and smells that we experience in a particular beer.

However, we have run into an issue in that many of these descriptors are often seen in a negative, and sometimes unpleasant, light.

Are there any words that are more appealing or romantic that can be used in place of words such as - funk, phenol, umami?

All of these words can be described - funk - barnyard, must, horse hoof - phenol - vinyl, medicinal, band aid - umami - earthy, savory - but they lack a concise descriptor that can be used to denote something innately positive. Something more in tune with how terroir is used to describe the effect that a particular region's climate, soils and aspect (terrain) change and impact the taste of wine.

Comment: fascinating question. The trouble is all those _sound_ unfavorable (except maybe umami). You're looking for synonyms of these right?

Comment: Not just synonyms, but ones that sound appealing to those who may never have experienced these flavors before.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Yes, synonyms, but appealing. The difficulty is that all the suggestions you've given as alternatives are possibly not in the direction you want, but they are also the only indication as to meaning. That is, can you give more wordy suggestions for these three that are positive to make it easier to identify (if they exist) positive single words?

Comment: E.g. for phenol. the label is clinical and so should have no 'negative' (you're literally smelling phenol I take it?). Are is there food or drink other than beer that give off phenol but that is considered pleasant? Sharp, acidic, light, tastes like ... I can't think of anything pleasant that tastes similar to vinyl/band-aids.

Comment: That is, I suppose, the question I was hoping to answer. To a first time drinker, if I were to describe a beer as any of the above words (funky, phenolic, umami), many of them carry innately negative connotations. My problem is that I can't seem to find synonyms that are innately positive, and can be used to describe the flavors found in beer.

Comment: @Karl  You will have many of us scratching our heads by your invitation to mine the terminology of wine and apply it to beer. I would suggest that the two beverages are, for the most part, mutually exclusive in respect.of wine-synonyms that are more "appealing" and "romantic" as per your question.. It's rather onerous to come up with "romantic" terminology without the risk of sounding pretentious, a state of affairs that respected wine writers and commentators would want to avoid. Ditto for beer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't look up the words that other breweries use?

Comment: I agree that I don't aim to sound pretentious, but at the same time for first time beer drinkers I do not want them to shy away from trying a beer simply because I say that it has a horse blanket taste, a common phenolic flavor and one that is often found in Saisons and other Belgian styles.

Comment: @Spagirl The problem that I am encountering is that almost no breweries are using terms that are approachable to the layperson, and if they are, I unfortunately haven't been able to find any. I was hoping someone more versed in the English language would be able to help with this predicament, which led me to pose the question here.

Comment: Have you looked at these companies? http://www.williamsbrosbrew.com/beer https://www.brewdog.com/beer/seasonal http://www.fyneales.com/beer/seasonals

Comment: Karl, I'm sure this is not the first time this subject has been discussed, especially within the beer tasting community. We could try here to speculate on good synonyms or phrases to describe (or just label blindly) these tastes, but I suspect they've already been given official terms that are accepted by the industry _and_ used by learners.

Comment: Take 'phenol'. Do you have other terms for this? Do you have a list of things that produce this taste/smell? Is it actually a desired taste? Where does it fit in with the other tastes? (bitter, sour, hoppy, fermented, yeasty, whatever (I'm just spitballing)). To come up with good _positive_ labels will also need a lot of domain specific knowledge.

Comment: I don't understand.  What do *you the tasting panel* think these taste like? Asking the internet for flavor words is like asking me to name your kids.  Further the examples given are already romantic words used in wine terrior descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your language.  Anyone who pays close attention to their own palate has realized long ago that nearly all delicious food and drink of any serious complexity has exotic characteristics that in excess are unappealing or even disgusting. Everything you've said is also frequently applied to wine.  As honest tasters, you give your reader an indication whether you find the characteristic appealing and balanced by other qualities or simply "too much".  "Delicious dark flavors with notes of truffle and woodland floor" is markedly different from "Swampy sulfurous notes overpower..."  "Tar and roses" is a classic descriptor for Barolo, just as "petrol and jasmine" is unmistakeable in a fine riesling.  You have a wonderful opportunity to open doors for your readers as to what is really going on with their own organoleptic experience of eating and drinking. To expand the descriptive vocabulary, read wine reviews and food reviews to see how others describe tastes and smells.